# How to edit routing for taxonomy listing?

Tags: routes, bolt-cms

I just installed Bolt CMS and managed to edit the routing for my pages, so the route is `/myPage` instead of `/page/myPage`.

Now I want to do something similar for listing of Category entries.
Currently to display all the entries in a Category the route looks like `/categories/myCategory`.
Is it possible to change the routing, so the route will be only `/myCategory`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the app/config/routing.yml docs you can do something like this.

```
categories:
  path:  /{slug}
  defaults:  { _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::taxonomy' }
  requirements:
    taxonomytype: 'categories'
```

Make sure this doesn't overwrite your page rule.

For more info you can check the documentation about Bolt Routing https://docs.bolt.cm/templates-routes#routing

Comment: Hi, thank you.
I checked the documentation, but was not sure how to edit the category listings... 

I tried your code (and some variations), but all I get is an error:
`Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 121`

Comment: Sorry, I made a little mistake.

You need to tell the function controller wich taxonomy you want to list.

`defaults: { _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::taxonomy', 'taxonomytype': 'categories' }`